# Trigger click event: addEventListener is not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering why a `addEventListener("click", function(){})` is not called when triggered by a jQuery `.trigger("click")` but it IS called when triggered by a `dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("foo");

$(el).click(function() { console.log("jquery click"); });
el.onclick = function() { console.log("onclick"); };
el.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("addEventlistener click"); });

$(el).trigger("click");
console.log("--------");
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#foo" id="foo">foo</a>
```

This produces the following console output

```
(index):54 jquery click
(index):55 onclick
(index):59 --------
(index):54 jquery click
(index):55 onclick
(index):56 addEventlistener click
```

Am I missing something? Does jQuery "fake" a click by calling it's event listeners directly?

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) for runnable examples so they're on-site. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: jQuery trigger runs synthetic events that do not work the same as native events, especially around click.

Comment: Thanks for your question! I was trying so hard to intercept a jQuery custom trigger event with vanilla JS addEventListener() and just couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery's `trigger` fires the jQuery handlers and calls the `.event()` function on the element* — **unless** it's a `click` on an `a` element, in which case it doesn't do that second part. (It also treats checkboxes specially.) E.g., we see it if we use a `div` in your example:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("foo");

$(el).click(function() { console.log("jquery click"); });
el.onclick = function() { console.log("onclick"); };
el.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("addEventlistener click"); });

$(el).trigger("click");
console.log("--------");
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but not on your `a`:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("foo");

$(el).click(function() { console.log("jquery click"); });
el.onclick = function() { console.log("onclick"); };
el.addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("addEventlistener click"); });

$(el).trigger("click");
console.log("--------");
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
```

```html
<a href="#foo" id="foo">foo</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why not? For "cross-browser consistency" the source says: See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L476 (that link is to a line number, and so <s>may</s> will rot):

```
    click: {

        // For checkbox, fire native event so checked state will be right
        trigger: function() {
            if ( this.type === "checkbox" && this.click && nodeName( this, "input" ) ) {
                this.click();
                return false;
            }
        },

        // For cross-browser consistency, don't fire native .click() on links
        _default: function( event ) {
            return nodeName( event.target, "a" );
        }
    },
```

Note that bit at the end.

---

* This is a bit tricky to find. [`trigger` says](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

> Any event handlers **attached with `.on()` or one of its shortcut methods** are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the `.trigger()` method.

...but [`triggerHandler` says](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/):

> The behavior of this method is similar to `.trigger()`, with the following exceptions:

- The `.triggerHandler( "event" )` method will not call `.event()` on the element it is triggered on. This means `.triggerHandler( "submit" )` on a form will not call `.submit()` on the form.
- While `.trigger()` will operate on all elements matched by the jQuery object, `.triggerHandler()` only affects the first matched element.
- Events triggered with `.triggerHandler()` do not bubble up the DOM hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly, they do nothing.
- Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining), `.triggerHandler()` returns whatever value was returned by the last handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers are triggered, it returns undefined

Could definitely be clearer on this point.

Answer (score 0):

trigger() has always been problematic for me.

The API says:

> Execute **all handlers** and behaviors attached to the matched elements
>   for the given event type.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

addEventListener behaves differently than inline click events and the browsers interpret the bubble differently:
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

When you dispatch, you are creating a custom event that circumvents these restrictions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

So, dispatch works around these limitations, while trigger() tries to do the work for you.